# Re-installing same or different OS on already created hyper-v virtual machine

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Cent-OS is installed on hyper-v virtual machine. I want to re-install same OS or different OS on same machine without deleting the data. Is it possible through **Powershell**?

Comment: Not really a PowerShell question and should be moved to the superuser Q&A. Windows allows upgrading in place without destroying data. I have not idea if CentOS allows this method. Yet, going from one OS to another means data destruction, if that data is on the OS drive. Move the data to a second drive and you are free to do as you wish, since OS installs only shoudl target the startup partition.

Comment: I think you may be able to tell the hyper-v host to mount a disk and to restart the vm. But automation of the OS installation inside the vm... There might be tools and ways to install a certain OS on Systems that join a special IP-network automatically... But how to do it step by step I have no ideas.

Comment: Thanks. It is not possible to copy data in the case of Cent-os reinstall.